# Fill a table without duplicates

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

I'm trying to fill a table With values from this table

```
CREATE TABLE PLATOS(Idplatos integer PRIMARY KEY, Tipo varchar(20), PlatoP varchar(20));

INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('1','entrada','ceviche');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('2','entrada','arrozleche');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('3','sopa','caldo');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('4','sopa','mote');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('5','plato','lomo');
INSERT INTO Platos VALUES('6','plato','rusa');
```

To this one:

```
Create table abril2017(nrodia integer,entrada varchar(20), sopa varchar(20), plato varchar(20),unique(entrada,sopa,plato));
```

I tried this code

```
    declare @nd int
    set @nd=1
    while @nd<=31
    begin

    Insert into  abril2017 values (@nd,
   (Select TOP 1 PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'entrada' oRDER BY NEWID()),
    (Select TOP 1 PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'sopa'  Order by NewId()),
    (Select TOP 1 PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'plato' oRDER by NewId()))
    SET @nd=@nd+1
    end
```

So far the results are okay, but the errors I don't want to have are:

> 1) nrodia, must be +1 only when a succesful insert happens, right now
>   It is +1 always and that ruins his purpose. nrodia means "daynumber".
>
> 2) Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'UQ__abril201__24030ECAAB418A64'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.abril2017'. The duplicate key value is (arrozleche, mote,
>   lomo). The statement has been terminated.

This error appears , but anyways all my values are inserted without duplicates, I just don't want to show this or something like that when you execute the last code of insert, I don't know if it's an error or just something similar?. 
In the end the code works and just those problems must be fixed, the first table will have actually 15 values not just 6, so in case someone could provide me the solution for a situation with more values will be better, thanks.

```
1   arrozleche  caldo   lomo
3   arrozleche  mote    lomo
4   ceviche     mote    lomo
5   ceviche     mote    rusa
7   arrozleche  mote    rusa
8   ceviche     caldo   rusa
11  ceviche     caldo   lomo
16  arrozleche  caldo   rusa
```

How you can see there are all the possible combinations with those values from the first table that doesn't repeat(but still shows the problem number 2) ), the numbers on the left must be 1,2,3... until the last row, in this case 8. That is just one example, if you use the code to insert you will have a different table because the values inserted are random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it , like this:

```
declare @nd int
set @nd=1
DECLARE @xEntrada VARCHAR(20), @xSopa varchar(20), @xPlato varchar(20)
DECLARE @xResultCount INT = 8
while @nd<=31
begin
    Select TOP 1 @xEntrada = PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'entrada' oRDER BY NEWID()
    Select TOP 1 @xSopa = PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'sopa'  Order by NewId()
    Select TOP 1 @xPlato = PlatoP from Platos where tipo = 'plato' oRDER by NewId()

    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM abril2017 WHERE Entrada = @xEntrada AND Sopa = @xSopa AND Plato = @xPlato))
    BEGIN
        Insert into  abril2017 values (@nd,@xEntrada,@xSopa,@xPlato)
        SET @nd=@nd+1
        SET @xResultCount = @xResultCount - 1
        IF(@xResultCount = 0)
            BREAK
    END
END;
```

Comment: wow fantastic, thank you so much It worked, althougth I don't know why I have to stop the execution of the query because it it's like "Executing query..." for minutes(And I had to stop it, but the values were actually inserted anyways), that's normal? Or maybe it's just my laptop? Thank you again (maybe in some time I will post another problem about this whole project)

Comment: it's not related to your laptop,
you must calculate count of all possible true results and after reaching to desired result using break command to stopping execution query

Comment: Uhmm I need to put some code to not have "infinite" executing query? Or put a limit? (I don't know how to do that :( ) With your help I advanced to the next step with this problem now it's about creating a procedure. Hope you can help me if you have a little more time :D.

Comment: the best practice is statistically calculation of all possible results, e.g regarding your sample data you have 2 value for 'entrada', 2 value for 'sopa', 2 value fo 'plato' so possible unique results count is 2!*2!*2! = 8 hence when your excecution of your code reached to this result, execution of code must stopping.

Comment: So if I have the possible unique results 3!*5!*7!=3628800, But I only will need 31 possible combinations or  28 for february for example. How Can I do that restriction or limitation?  Thanks for all your help

Comment: I edited the above answer for this purpose, is it clear?

Comment: Yep, thank you so much, I have seen some errors with the procedure I'm trying to create right now thanks to your answer too :)